# Error while deleting coor from touch . 'near ",": syntax error''

Tags: ios, database, uiwebview, sqlite

I have UIWebView for displays HTML article pages. I used UILongPressGesture for getting touch location coordinates. I saved these coordinates to database. Every coordinates having button. Now i need to delete one of these coordinates from database while clicking on button. So, here i'm getting coordinates from database and coordinates match with current location then i delete the particular cooridate button. But it's not deleting

```
 if(x1 && y1){

        NSLog(@"x1 is %f",x1);
        NSLog(@"y1 is %f",y1);


        sqlite3_stmt *addStmt;

       // const char *sqlDelete = "DELETE xcoor,ycoor FROM touch";


         const char *sqlDelete = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"delete FROM touch where xcoor = '%f','%f'",x1,y1] cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

        if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sqlDelete, -1, &addStmt, NULL) != SQLITE_OK)
            NSAssert1(0, @"Error while deleting coor from touch . '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database));

        NSLog(@"%s error finalizing %s", __FUNCTION__, sqlite3_errmsg(database));

        if(SQLITE_DONE != sqlite3_step(addStmt))
            NSAssert1(0, @"Error while deleting coor from touch . '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database));


}
```

x1 & y1 is the current location coordinates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const char *sqlDelete = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"delete FROM touch where xcoor = %f AND ycoor = %f",x1,y1] cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

replace your delete statement with this it will work